# Images in mobile application

Tags: android, database, image

So there is an application which let's say shows images. So I know that it's a bad practice to store images in database so where should I store it? In some remote server and then access images somehow?

Please someone explain whole process. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use any third party cdn like cloudinary

Answer (score 1):

You can save the image in SD card and show it. For example you are taking one picture by using camera and save this to SD card and you can use it in your application. In another case image coming from server in this case you need to download the images and you save this it into SD card.

Basically in any case you want to use an image just create one folder and save image inside of that folder. You can use it from your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is store the images in the device storage.
You can either store the image as another file type you like or keep the file type as normal image.

However, if you want to know about it further you can read the documentation by Google [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).